# How can I finish the concrete block wall along my basement steps with drywall?

Tags: framing, basement-refinishing

I'm finishing my 50 year old basement and need advice on finishing the wall by the stairs.   There's only 2 inches to the inside edge of the stringer so no room for 2x4s. Would strapping backed with a gasket and the stair stringer as the baseplate work? I could replace the moulding along the top for something thicker and use that as a top plate.
I'm open to alternatives!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does 'finishing' mean you want to cover the concrete block with drywall? Did you already consider using an adhesive to fix the sheets directly to the blocks?

Comment: Are you looking to insulate?  Or do you just want a look other than painted brick?

Comment: @GregHill - yes to drywall.  I didn't think attaching drywall directly to the blocks was a good idea due to potential condensation near the top where the plastic for the interior weeping system ends.Also the weight of the drywall might not be supported by the plastic.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore - yes insullation.  Rockwool in the rest of the basement but due to minimal space here I'm considering 1 - 1.5" rigid foam. Or stripping down the rockwool.  I'm just not sure the strapping attached to the stringer is a good idea or if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Does the wall sweat or leak ?

If not then I would affix  finish grade 1/2" plywood with adhesive.

It would be less messy to get off then dry wall if you had to and it would allow you hang photo or art with small screws.

You could mount it directly to the blocks or you could put very thin 1/4" slats as furring strip on with construction adhesive ( better i think ) and then attach it ( or drywall ) to the furring strips.

You could even do 2'x2' squares and stain/paint each one with its own shade/color.

Just saying,  outside the box thinking.

**P.S.** *this could also apply to your other question about the concrete ceiling.*

Comment: I've installed drywall directly on a concrete wall in the same scenario, using concrete screws to hold the sheet while the adhesive sets.